# Joining the negative PV wires of 3 solar arrays for 3 MPPT controllers in an inverter?

Tags: solar-energy, photovoltaics, solar

My Inverter has 3 MPPT inputs. For some design simplifications (Involving ATS), i would like the three arrays to have separate PV+ but join the PV- wires together at a bus-bar and take the Inverter negative DC input from there.[image: effective layout of the setup]

Will this have an effect on the performance of MPPT operating independently? or should i keep the PV- wires separate?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the inverter, if the maker provides 3 separate pv- then I would keep them separate. If they could be joined together, then the maker would have done so.

Comment: i have an ATS that switches PV power between a Grid Tied inverter and a solar pumping inverter. there is a combiner box at the solar pumping inverter side where the arrays are made parallel. 

While i have contactors for the pv+ to switch between the Grid Tied inverter And the solar pumping inverter, I dont have the alloted budget to put contactors in ATS for the PV- as well. the diagram provided is simplified, what i have are multiple 36kW inverters where in such is the case. the Makers did separate the PV- but i wonder what will be the performance loss if any if pv- is made common.

Comment: So draw the correct diagram of yhe actual situation with the details necessary.

Comment: This question is a better fit for SE Electrical Engineering. | "Electrically"  in an ideal situation, combining the -ve leads of three separate MPPT inverters would be without negative consequence. There MAY be code issues (although what they may be and why I know not). Trying to think ahead of Murphy, I'd look for what non idealities MIGHT exist to make a difference.  eg combining the negatives at the panels and running a single connection to the inverters MAY result in some interactions. (I'd expect it to be small, but combining the negatives at the inverters seems liable to be better).

Comment: Does each inverter connect PV -ve to output neutral and/or ground? If not then the PV array per inverter may float relative to output in some manner under inverter control. Combining the input -ves MAY influence this. || I'd expect the inverter manufacturer to have a clear statement on this. || I'd expect it t be OK but would look very hard at "what could possibly go wrong :-) ".